# How is the starting grid determined?

Tags: motorsport-manager

At the beginning of each race, how is the starting grid determined?

Often, in real life, the grid is determined with the championship position of the driver in reverse order. Let's say you are rated 12th on 20 drivers and we follow this rule, then you would start at the 8th position.

I was wondering if it's always the case in Motorsport Manager, or if some voted rules can change how the grid is arranged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the rule:

- Qualifying-based Grids (1st goes 1st, 2nd goes 2nd, etc..)
- Qualifying-based Grids with 3 Sessions (1st goes 1st, 2nd goes 2nd, etc.. Qualification done over 3 sessons instead of just 1)
- Reversed Driver's Championship Grids (Driver with **least** points goes 1st, Driver with the **most** points goes last)
- Grid Position is random (Anyone can go anywhere)
- Grid Positon is determined by League Standing (Driver with the **most** points goes 1st, Driver with the **least** goes last

And you can propose/vote on the rule to change